# accessing activemq ajax amq.js from .net mvc3 website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, activemq-classic

I have a .net mvc3 site and want to use the ActiveMq amq.js ajax call feature from javascript. The problem is according to chat demo feature..it requires configuring servlets to access java classes but thats not possible in c# application

Any Ideas or leads. (Basically need a way to access activemq topic without having to manually writing a timer based polling code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ supports the STOMP protocol over websockets http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html. Using this you don't need to set up any servlets, just configure the broker to expose the appropriate transportConnector. There are a number of STOMP/websocket Javascript libraries such as Stomple (https://github.com/krukow/stomple) that you can then use to easily access topics.

Comment: Only annoyance is not all the major 3 browsers (IE 9) support it